# Check-out file by users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, check-out, lock

The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user share point document library? None of the users locked this document. I have a farm admin account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a site admin/ sca you should be able to override the checkout. Select the item/file drop down and click Override checkout. Usually if a file is locked by a user, the lock is release after 5 to 10 minutes.